# How to disable all inputs inside `<div>` in SharePoint 2013 form?

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, edit-form, newform

I want to disabled/readonly inputs on some fields in SharePoint 2013 New/Edit forms based on a field's value.

So I manually add `<div>` around group of `<tr>`.

```
<div id='myDiv'> 
<tr>...</tr>
...
<tr>...</tr>
</div>
```

I have tried two different method, see code below:

```
$("#myDiv *").prop("disabled", true); 
$("#myDiv").children().prop('disabled',true);
```

Neither one is working. I have to disabled each field one by one.

Any suggestion for the `<div>` coding would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like:

```
$("#myDiv input").prop("disabled", true);
$("#myDiv select").prop("disabled", true);
$("#myDiv textarea").prop("disabled", true);
```

I tried below and it's working:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
    <tr>
        <td>Input1</td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Input2</td>
        <td><input type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Input3</td>
        <td><textarea rows="3"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myDiv input").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#myDiv select").prop("disabled", true);
        $("#myDiv textarea").prop("disabled", true);
    });
</script>
```

[CodePen Reference](https://codepen.io/ganeshsanap/pen/rNNBKZP).

**Update**:

This is working for me on SharePoint list forms as well, see below output and code I have used:

[image]

Comment: I used the same js code, it doesn't work.  The field is still editable.

Comment: Can you please check the codepen reference... Which is working fine for me.

Comment: It works on CodePen.  Is there any special in Sharepoint 2013?  I add '<div>' manually using SPD.

Comment: Try adding breakpoint in `document.ready()` and check if you are getting the div element using `$("#myDiv")`

Comment: Hi Ganesh - I do get div element.

Comment: Then I guess it should work. Check using `$("#myDiv input")` how many input fields you are getting.... Also check if all inputs/tr elements are inside your div element or not.

Comment: It shows '0'. I try 'textarea' too.  All of them are '0'.

Comment: Can you please check if you have missed end tag for div element or something. All inputs and tr elements are properly wrapped inside div element? Can you please add screenshot of html code by inspecting your list form?

Comment: There must be something you are missing, can you please check using the div with your web part ID (div ID will be starting with something like `WebPartWPQ`) instead of the div you are appending using code?

Comment: How to attach a file to show source code?  Thanks!

Comment: See one detail '<tr>' inside '<div>'.      <div id="myDiv"> <tr><td width='190px' valign='top' class='ms-formalabel'><H3 class='ms-standardheader'><nobr>Release</nobr></H3></td><td width='400px' valign='top' class='ms-formbody'><span dir='none'><input name='ctl....$TextField' type='text' maxlength='255' id='ctl..._TextField' title='Release' class='ms-long ms-spellcheck-true'/><br/></span></td></tr><tr>...</tr>  </div>